# Error: common: unmarshalJSON failed: hash must be exactly 32 bytes(…)?

Tags: web3js

I have a simple meteor app that is running on a local node on a private chain. I am attempting to send some ether from one test account to another, and I get the following error, from inside the getR() function. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

`Error: common: unmarshalJSON failed: hash must be exactly 32 bytes(…)?`

here is the getR() function, please see full code snippet below for context:

```
var getR = function() {
    console.log(window.transactionHash);
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(window.transactionHash, function(err, receipt){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(receipt);
    // document.getElementById("response2").innerHTML = receipt.transactionHash;
});

};
```

* inside of the this function `err` returns the error stated in the title, and the receipt object is null.

```
<body>
    <h3>Account</h3>
    <p id="account"></p>
    <h3>Account Balance</h3>
    <p id="balance"></p> ether
    <button id="sendEther" onclick="sendSomeEther()">Send 1 Ether</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
    <button id="getR" onclick="getR()">What Happened!</button>
    <p id="response2"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.web3 = new Web3();
    window.transactionHash = '';
    alert(window);

    var getR = function() {
        console.log(window.transactionHash);

        web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(window.transactionHash, function(err, receipt){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(receipt);
            // document.getElementById("response2").innerHTML = receipt.transactionHash;
        });
    };

    function sendSomeEther(){
        var txObject = {
            from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
            gas: 30000000,
            value: web3.toWei(12, 'ether'),
            to: 'ac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c'
        };

        web3.eth.sendTransaction(txObject, function(err, result){
            if(err)
            return document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 'Error: ' + err;

            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 'Yay, first one! transaction hash:' + result;

            window.transactionHash = result;
        });
    };

    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

        document.getElementById("account").innerHTML = accounts[0];

        web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0], function(err, balance){
            document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether');

        });
    });


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: 1) Is window.transactionHash shown correctly in the console before the call? 2) Is the transaction mined? [Recepits are not available for pending transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Please see below. I unlocked the sending account while starting geth - and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

Follow instructions from this post, on unlocking an account with the --unlock flag - while starting geth. Once the sending account was unlocked in the current geth instance, the transaction was successful.

[Error: account is locked. Attempting to send ether from one account to another, Local Node on Private Blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/error-account-is-locked-attempting-to-send-ether-from-one-account-to-another)