# Error: account is locked. Attempting to send ether from one account to another, Local Node on Private Blockchain

Tags: web3js, accounts

What is the correct process to unlock an account? I was able to do this successfully in the geth console(see this post for more details on what I've tried [Why does account show 0 balance, after seemingly successful transaction in geth console?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4579/why-does-account-show-0-balance-after-seemingly-successful-transaction-in-geth?noredirect=1#comment4877_4579))

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are a few ways to unlock an account

1. While starting geth, you can use `--unlock`

> Unlock an account (may be creation index) until this program exits (prompts for password). `--unlock` takes multiple params, it could be an index of your account like `0, 2, 3` or it can be an address `0x12a..` or this can be `primary` to unlock primary account.

2. from the geth console

> `personal.unlockAccount(address, "password")`

#### Unlock multiple accounts from the command line

```
  --unlock      Unlock an account (may be creation index) until this program exits (prompts for password)
  --password    Password file to use with options/subcommands needing a pass phrase
```

#### Command example

`geth --unlock primary --password "/path/to/file"` this will unlock your `primary` account if the password specified in `"/path/to/file"` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

From [How to unlock accounts programmatically after the node has started?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-unlock-accounts-programmatically-after-the-node-has-started/2687#2687) :

```
> geth --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'password', 1000)" attach
true
```

You are probably using the RPC API interface, so will need to enable the `personal` API using

```
geth [your options] --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,admin" [more options]
```

But be careful with the RPC API and the unlocking of your wallet if you hold real ethers in your wallet. See [How to reduce the chances of your Ethereum wallet getting hacked?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-reduce-the-chances-of-your-ethereum-wallet-getting-hacked).

Comment: for now, is running on a private testnet. No real ethers yet

Comment: @matthewalexander Did you figure this out?

Comment: The accepted answer in this thread solved my problem I believe